# Positioning windows with applescript

Tags: macos, position, applescript

I want to set the position of some windows to certain coordinates.

In particular I have 4 possible positions that those windows should have.

For example if I have 4 windows opened I want them to go one per each position, instead if I have 6 windows opened I want the first 4 windows to go to to position 1,2,3,4 then the last 2 to position 1 and 2. I mean if I had 12 windows opened those should go to position 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4.

At the moment I've managed to get the IDs of those windows in a list.

```
--list with all windows
set Auch to {...}

repeat with theWindow in Auch
    tell (windows whose title contains theWindow) -- it's working
        activate
        set position to {200, 20} --position #1
    end tell
end repeat
```

This is the code I've written: I'm sure there's a smart way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
set positions to {{100,100},{200,100},{100,200},{200,200}} -- adjust as you like...
set idx to 0 -- we'll need a counter

--list with all windows
set Auch to {...}

repeat with theWindow in Auch
    tell (windows whose title contains theWindow) -- it's working
        activate
        set position to (item ((idx % 4) + 1) of positions)
        set idx to idx + 1 
    end tell
end repeat
```

I've not tried it but should work. Hope it helps or at least give you the idea.

The % (modulus) operator returns the remainder of the division of the value before by the value after.

So ((idx % 4) + 1) will result (over the iterations) in 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...